# Why's the second condition always firing even though it's not being fufilled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm checking to see if the file uploaded is > 5MB.  If it is, throw the error message and clear the value of the upload.  That works fine.

I also want to check if the file is a `.mov` type.  If it is, throw the error message and clear the value of the upload.

I can't see why my second condition is always firing.  I want it to be where if a `.mov` file type is uploaded, only the 2nd if condition's error message is being thrown and not the first if condition's error message (completely ignore it).

I've tried using `else if` and `else {if(...)}` but that didn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).on('change', '.uploadedFile', function () {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
        var fileType = /\.(mov)$/i.test(this.files[0]);

        if(fileSize > 5) {
            alert("The video you've uploaded is " + Math.round(fileSize) + "MB.  Please upload a video that's 5MB or less!");
            $('.uploadedFile').val('');
        }

        if(!fileType) {
            alert("Only .mp4 file types are allowed");
            $('.uploadedFile').val('');
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you want to check only one condition then you can't have the code check multiple conditions sequentially. It's unclear what you tried, but it seems like if you want to check for filetype first then you should check for it first and return rather than continuing to check other conditions.

Comment: You should `return false` in your 1st IF statement. Since you don;'t do this, it's proceeding with the next IF statement.

Comment: @Twisty your suggestion ALMOST works but now when I try to upload a video < 5MB, the second if fires (even though it's a .mp4 type and it's < 5MB).

Comment: @whenitrainsitpours your regular expression check is for `.mov` not for `.mp4`. This would cause it not to pass the check. Consider changing your check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(document).on('change', '.uploadedFile', function() {
  var fileSize = this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
  var fileType = /\.(mov|mpg|mp4)$/i.test(this.files[0]);

  if (!fileType && fileSize > 5) {
    alert("Please upload only .mov, .mpg, or .mp4 Files that are no more than 5 MB.");
    return false;
  }
});
```

This combines both checks into one condition. They both must be met to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `return` end of first `if` to prevent run other `if` condition.

```
$(document).on('change', '.uploadedFile', function () {
            var fileSize = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
            var fileType = /\.(mov)$/i.test(this.files[0]);
    
            if(fileSize > 5) {
                alert("The video you've uploaded is " + Math.round(fileSize) + "MB.  Please upload a video that's 5MB or less!");
                $('.uploadedFile').val('');
                return;
            }
    
            if(!fileType) {
                alert("Only .mp4 file types are allowed");
                $('.uploadedFile').val('');
            }
        });
```

OR you can try this, Set your second `if` in `else` state of first `if`:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.uploadedFile', function () {
            var fileSize = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
            var fileType = /\.(mov)$/i.test(this.files[0]);

            if(fileSize > 5) {
                alert("The video you've uploaded is " + Math.round(fileSize) + "MB.  Please upload a video that's 5MB or less!");
                $('.uploadedFile').val('');
                
            } else{
             if(!fileType) {
                alert("Only .mp4 file types are allowed");
                $('.uploadedFile').val('');
            }
           }

           
        });
```